# 'PERL_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, cmake

While trying to compile [amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp-repo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp) I am getting an error `'PERL_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I find this error strange and cannot find any solution online. I have installed ActivePerl and I am using Windows 10. I have added the following paths(where ActivePerl is installed) to environment variables also:

```
C:\Users\amay\AppData\Local\activestate\bin    
C:\Users\amay\AppData\Local\activestate\bin\perl.exe
C:\Users\amay\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\bin
```

If I run `perl -v` on cmd it works fine so I am assuming the paths are not the issue here. I am running this command: `cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DBUILD_GSTREAMER_PLUGIN=ON` on x64 Native Tools Command Prompt VS 2017.

Here is the error:

```
[ 67%] Linking C executable lib1518.exe
[ 67%] Built target lib1518
Scanning dependencies of target lib1520
[ 67%] Building C object tests/libtest/CMakeFiles/lib1520.dir/lib1520.c.obj
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MDd' with '/MTd'
lib1520.c
[ 67%] Building C object tests/libtest/CMakeFiles/lib1520.dir/first.c.obj
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MDd' with '/MTd'
first.c
[ 67%] Linking C executable lib1520.exe
[ 67%] Built target lib1520
[ 67%] Generating lib1521.c
'PERL_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'PERL_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
CMake Error at dependency/libkvscproducer/kvscproducer-src/CMake/Utilities.cmake:93 (message):
  CMake step for libcurl failed: 2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dependency/libkvscproducer/kvscproducer-src/CMakeLists.txt:86 (build_dependency)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/amay/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it is. The perl -v command also works on cmd.

Comment: I tried to build this on Windows 10 with Strawberry Perl 5.32.1, x64 Native Tools Command Prompt VS 2019. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Xx7u0PFE) is my build log. I get the error *"LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'apps\app_rand.obj'"*. I think it has been reported [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/12563) before.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I had the same issue but after running the same cmake command again, this error was resolved. No idea why.  I read [link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/conan-io/conan-center-index/4740/828077446) and excuted the cmake command again after getting the error and it woked.

Comment: *"I executed the cmake command again ..."* Yes, executing the same command again fixed the first issue. But now I get another error: `Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0' ... A required package was not found`. [Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hakonhagland/b575f1d9d4aaf16b0aa249a1b8d11dc5/raw/c93d5f65c3cd15ff7c7c7432c9646711388f5aa5/log.txt) is the complete output.

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues/715)